# Partial dimensions in python

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I declare multidimensional arrays in python and print its shape using numpy as:

```
B=[[2,3,4]]
print(np.shape(B))
```

it gives the following output:

```
(1,3)
```

This is understandable as the inner bracket would represent the second dimension which has 3 components.

But when I run the following code:

```
B=[2,3,4]
print(np.shape(B))
```

It prints:

```
(3,)
```

How do I explain these partial dimensions to myself?

It means the second dimension exists but the number of elements are unknown in it.How does one infer from array [2,3,4] that a second dimension exists?Should'nt the shape just be (3)?

Comment: As far as I know, this is just the way in which python prints tuples containing just 1 element. If you try `print tuple([2])` you will get `(2,)`.

Comment: `(3)` is not a `tuple`, you have to declare it as `(3,)`, otherwise it's just an integer in parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem of syntax.  `(3,)` is the tuple (3), since `(3)` is interpreted like the integer 3.